# Hazelcast 3.12 IMap.lock() on Map better than ILock.lock() which is deprecated?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is Hazelcast IMap.lock() on Map better than ILock.lock() which is deprecated in version 3.12? Can we continue with the usage of IMap.lock() or is it too projected to be deprecated? 
What are the specific advantages of using locks on Map?
Are locks on the map written on the same partition as that of the key?
If so, where(which area of Hazelcast Distributed memory) are the general locks not tied to maps written to?

```
Lock mylock = Hazelcast.getLock(mylockobject); 
mylock.lock(); **//Deprecated**

 try {
      //dosomething
 }finally{
  mylock.unlock();
 }      

IMap map = Hazelcast.getMap("customers"); map.lock("1"); //Not deprecated
 try {
//dosomething
 }finally{
 map.unlock("1"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IMap.lock(key)` creates a lock object for that key on the same partition while other keys are still available whereas `ILock.lock(object)` is a distributed form of reentrant lock that controls access to the object. So, there is no relation between the two.

ILock is being deprecated for a much better version **FencedLock**, see here for details: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.2/manual/html-single/index.html#lock